# Can RED and BLACK wire from ceiling connected to ONE BLACK WIRE of FAN with integrated lighting (i.e no seperate light wire)?

Tags: wiring, ceiling-fan

I have two fan switches that operate a bulb (but not in a 3-way configuration). Both the red and black wires are connected to the bulb so either switch will turn on the light but only *both* off will turn off the bulb.

The new fan has no separate light wire (integrated lighting control).

Can the red & black ceiling wires connect to fan's single black wire like the bulb is connected?

I prefer to not cap the red wire and leave one switch not operating anything.

[image: wiring at the current ceiling light fixture]

Comment: Are the two switches at the same location, or are they in different places?

Comment: Why do you _prefer_ to not cap one wire at both ends and leave a non-functioning switch? There's absolutely nothing wrong with that. You could even put a label on the inside of the cover plate indicating that the switch is intentionally disabled and what it operates in case someone in the future wants to reenable it.

Comment: Actually, it appears to me that a previous person did exactly the opposite of what you're doing and created this confusion. I'll bet that there used to be a ceiling fan here and that you had one switch for the fan and one for the lights. The previous owner didn't want to cap a wire (for whatever reason) and created this very non-standard and confusing set up where you now have two switches configured in an `OR` situation. Simply fix it the same way the last guy should have.

Answer (score 2):

There's no reason you can't do what you want so that either switch on turns on the fan.

However, my preference would be to remove one switch (cap both ends of the wire) and use a two-gang, single switch plate to hide the missing switch:
[image]
or
[image]

Comment: This is actually the best solution as attempting to run the hot power over _both_ of 2 different wires within the same cable will, most likely, cause all sorts of issues, and might just be illegal.